# ANSYS: Why do I have a choice of choosing TOP/BOTTOM under contact/target shell faces?

Tags: finite-element-method, ansys

When ever I try to use a surface to surface contact, i.e. 2D shell elements to 2D shell elements, under the option Contact/Target shell face, either I can pick TOP or BOTTOM. Why is that? How is that going to cause trouble if I don't choose it correctly? Why is that important and how can I pick the correct shell faces?

Comment: Anyone on this one, please?

Comment: Is it on Ansys Classic APDL or WorkBench?

Answer (score 1):

A shell element has zero thickness but two sides called top and bottom. In Workbench you have to choose on both contacting shells the side that faces the other shell in order to achieve a working contact.

If the faces are chosen incorrectly, the contact will not work.

Comment: actually my question was exactly what you have written. I mean why does it matter if I choose it incorrectly? What is the importance of choosing TOP or BOTTOM face for a surface body (since it doesn't invlove any thickness at all). Why won't the contact work properly if chosen wrong? I heard somewhere that for bonded contact, it is not a problem whether you choose TOP or BOTTOM, but for a non-linear contact like frictional or frictionless, it matters what face you choose.

Comment: It has no thickness but two sides, like a sheet of paper. Can you write on the bottom side if it is on the table? You can't. With contacts ist just the same.

Comment: why does chosen the wrong side could affect the way my contact works?

Comment: Imagine you are moving 2 objects closer and closer until they have a contact. If you simulate this using shell elements with wrong orientation, the software may think there is a contact from the beginning and when the object actually make a contact, the contact according to software ceases to exist.

Comment: Also each face of the shell can have different contact properties. It is not like thin bodies have to have exactly same properties on both sides.